# Magento 2 custom module admin grid item duplicate

Tags: duplicates, grid, magento2, admin

I try to create custom admin grid. When I search for information It can be searched But after I cancel the search The result is a duplicate of every item.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it is resolve a problem

```
  <dataSource name="modulename_logger_index_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
        <settings>
            <storageConfig>
                <param name="cacheRequests" xsi:type="boolean">false</param>
            </storageConfig>
            <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Company\ModuleName\UI\DataProvider\Logger\DataProvider"
                      name="modulename_logger_index_listing_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>waitingtask_id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>waitingtask_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
```

Comment: What problem? how??

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this issue it by adding the `storageConfig` and the `indexField` item under the settings tag.

It will be something like this (Comments on the code will give you more information):

```xml
    <dataSource name="push_notification_pushNotificationLog_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <!-- ... -->
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <!-- Add below tag -->
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <!-- Set it to your table primary key -->
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    <!-- ... -->
    </dataSource>
```